# Xchat IRC , two nicks

Tags: 12.04, xchat

Hi i don't think this is a possible one but i am trying to get some help . I have two different nicknames belongs two two different accounts in freenode . so may i use Xchat IRC to access freenode with those two nicks ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As i understand it, *if* you own both accounts, you could, in theory, just open up two xchat sessions, have one nickname in each, and access them that way.

Alternately set up two network profiles, uncheck use global information and set information for each seperately - this will let you use two different passwords, and autojoin both

However you will want to check if the server/network has a connection limit.

If you do *not* own these nicknames, and they are registered by someone else, you are out of luck.Nickserv will force change your name, as part of nick protection, if you do not authenticate with a password for that account.

Comment: thats a good point , but every time if have opened xchat 2nd time i have to replace the nicks with 2nd nick id . so is there any solution i can have ?

Comment: set the second nick as your first alternate nick, naturally. First nick will fail, second nick will connect

Comment: but passwords are different right ? so i have to set same password for both i think ?

Comment: Nope, you can /msg nickserv identify each. I wonder if you could, alternately set up two profiles with different per profile info instead...

Comment: Yes, you can. Answer edited